# How to find distance between two points in shown diagram.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In figure below P1 is center of circle whose radius is known, say 'r'. Distance of point M from P1,P2 and P3 is known. How to find out length of D (shown in red line).

[image]

@EDIT : All distances are in Latitude/Longitude form.

I appreciate any help in this regards.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what the other endpoint of that line is. It's some point on the circle, but which point? You can't answer the question without that information.

Comment: @GerryMyerson We are using two different algorithms to calculate distance from point P1. One algorithm defines range. That means my point should be on circle (anywhere but on (not in but on) circle). Second algorithm gives approximate distance. Both algorithm has medium accuracy. We are trying to mix both algorithm. And it is standard practice to mix the both. Now from second algorithm, if I get distance equal to radius of circle, we will accept distance otherwise we need to adjust according to circle's radius.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand --- but I maintain that there must be something special about $D$ that you aren't telling us. From the diagram, all we know about $D$ is that it's on the circle, and different points on the circle are at different distances from $M$.

Comment: "How to find the length of D..." ...length=the distance from **where**?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not really allowed to tell about D.

Comment: @DonAntonio Distance from circle's circumference to point M. Circumference point, M and P1 are in straight line (sorry for not so good diagram).

Comment: Ah! So the point on the circle **is** special! Why was getting that information out of you as hard as pulling teeth?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sorry for incorrect way of asking question. I want to know point of intersection of circle from P1 to M (T).

Comment: Well, if you know the radius of the circle, and you know the distance from $M$ to the center of the circle, then the distance you want is just the difference between those two numbers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Please note it is about lat/long, not normal distance.

Comment: You know the distance from $M$ to $P$, right? And you know the distance from $T$ to $P$, right? And you want the distance from $M$ to $T$, right? And the three points are on the same line, right? So, what does latitude and longitude have to do with it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean it is coordinated system, not plane value. I want both x and y, not just simple value v. Hopefully I am able to explain my point.

Comment: The question asks for a distance, and only for a distance. If you want something else, please edit the question so it asks what you actually want it to ask. Sheesh.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure I think I asked question in wrong way. I will re-frame it again soon. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since this is obviously related to triangulation from cell towers (probably for a smart-phone app), you can share what it is you're trying to do without fear.  Otherwise, you've already likely broken any NDA.

Comment: @MarkPing Guessed it correctly.

Comment: I have re framed question again. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457798/how-to-find-p1-in-x-y-form

Answer (score 0):

You know: $DM^2=TD^2+TM^2$, $TM=MP1-r$ and $TD=r\sin(Tp1D)$

$DM^2=r^2 \sin(Tp1D)^2+(MP1-r)^2$
$DM^2=r^2\sin(Tp1D)^2+MP1^2-2rMP1+r^2$

if you need to have a better result than $DM^2=TD^2+TM^2$ you can
$DM=\sqrt{(TD^2+TM^2)}+\sqrt{(r^2\sin(Tp1D)^2-TD^2)}$